# Cloud Firestore with gRPC build error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, grpc, google-cloud-firestore

I’m working on an android application, which have to use gRPC and Firestore. However, when I added both one of module from ‘io.grpc’ group dependency (e.g. io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.7.0) and firestore dependency (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2) in the build gradle config, I got a build error “Unable to merge dex”. After with ‘stacktrace’ build option, I saw that the problem is

```
Multiple dex files define Lio/grpc/internal/OobChannel$5;
```

It could happen if firestore uses grpc-core module, but there is no one similar in tree dependencies, which I got using [androidDependencies] gradle task. I tried to exclude io.grpc like this:

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2') {
    exclude group: 'io.grpc'
}
```

but there was the same error.  Then I thought what if I exclude all ‘io.grpc.’ transitive dependencies from grpc module dependencies with adding grpc-core for internal classes. In this way, I wrote ugly dependencies just for test

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
implementation('io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.7.0') {
    exclude group: 'io.grpc'
}
implementation('io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.7.0') {
    exclude group: 'io.grpc'
}
implementation('io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.7.0') {
    exclude group: 'io.grpc'
}
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-core:1.7.0'
```

I was surprised when it successfully compiled, but after launch app, it crashed with java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzcyc()Lio/grpc/ManagedChannelProvider; in class Lio/grpc/ManagedChannelProvider; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider' appears in /data/app/com.zipr.test-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

I use gradle 3.0.0-rc1 with enabling multidex support. I deleted .gradle, build directories, cleaned rebuilt project,  but I still have build error. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to a variety of factors that constrain the way we build Android SDKs at Google, Firestore proguards a copy of gRPC within itself. Unfortunately this is leaky and you're running into the fallout: the 11.4.2 Firestore SDK is incompatible with any external gRPC :-(.

This is essentially our top issue for the Firestore Android SDK and I'm sorry you've run into it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, hope this issue will be resolved!

Comment: Is this thing fixed?

Comment: Is this thing fixed? I still have the same issue

Comment: This issue is 2.5 years old and since then Firestore has been open sourced and the build system completely changed. This issue certainly has been fixed, but it's possible you're encountering something else. Your best bet is to open an issue on github with the details of your environment, including what other dependencies you're using. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/new/choose